# Cross timeline count across subscriptions for customers

Tags: sql, mysql, intervals, gaps-and-islands

I have a subscription table with 4 fields: id, customer_id, start_date and end_date.
It lists all subscriptions of my customers. No subscription has an empty end_date, and a customer can have several subscriptions at once.

For example, a customer id 37 can have the following subscriptions:

| id | customer_id | start_at | end_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 44 | 37 | 2019-03-21 | 2019-03-21 |
| 17819 | 37 | 2020-03-23 | 2020-03-23 |
| 22302 | 37 | 2020-04-24 | 2021-07-25 |
| 42213 | 37 | 2021-04-25 | 2023-04-26 |
| 92013 | 37 | 2023-04-26 | 2024-04-26 |

These records mean that customer 37 was a subscriber on 2019-03-21, then on 2020-03-23, then from 2020-04-24 to 2024-04-26, for a total of 1463 days.

I am trying to write a query to get the number of days each customer has been a subscriber in a given period.
Customer 37 has been a subscriber 365 days in 2023.
Subscriptions can overlap, as a subscriber can have multiple subscriptions at once.

The result of the query should be something like:

| customer_id | total_subscription_days |
| --- | --- |
| 37 | 1463 |
| 38 | 526 |
| 39 | 426 |
| 40 | 365 |
| 41 | 325 |

My database is running on MySQL 8.2.12.

I tried using lag, lead, CTEs, least and greatest, to no avail. I tried chatgpt and stackoverflow.

EDIT: here below is what I tried so far:

1st try:

```sql
SELECT 
    customer_id,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(
        LEAST(end_at, '2023-12-31'), 
        GREATEST(start_at, '2023-01-01')
    ) + 1) AS total_subscription_days
FROM (
    SELECT 
        customer_id,
        start_at,
        end_at
    FROM 
        subscription
    WHERE 
        start_at <= '2023-12-31' AND end_at >= '2023-01-01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        s1.customer_id,
        LEAD(s1.end_at) OVER (PARTITION BY s1.customer_id ORDER BY s1.end_at),
        '2023-12-31'
    FROM 
        subscription s1
    LEFT JOIN 
        subscription s2 ON s1.customer_id = s2.customer_id 
                       AND s1.end_at < s2.start_at
    WHERE 
        s2.start_at IS NOT NULL
) AS merged_subscriptions
GROUP BY 
    customer_id;
```

Even though I wanted to know subscription days in 2023, I had results bigger than 365 days. So it seems to count duplicates because of the join.

2nd try:

```sql
WITH subscription_periods AS (
    SELECT 
        customer_id,
        start_at,
        end_at,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY start_at) AS period_number
    FROM 
        subscription
    WHERE 
        start_at <= '2023-12-31' AND end_at >= '2023-01-01' AND customer_id < 100
),
subscription_days AS (
    SELECT 
        customer_id,
        SUM(
            DATEDIFF(
                LEAST(end_at, '2023-12-31'), 
                GREATEST(start_at, '2023-01-01')
            ) + 1
        ) AS days
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                customer_id,
                start_at,
                LEAD(end_at) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY start_at) AS end_at
            FROM 
                subscription_periods
        ) AS overlapping_periods
    WHERE 
        end_at >= '2023-01-01'
    GROUP BY 
        customer_id
)
SELECT 
    customer_id,
    SUM(days) AS total_subscription_days
FROM 
    subscription_days
GROUP BY 
    customer_id;
```

I restricted to the first 100 customers, otherwise I was getting a 504 error.
This query seems to not be able to take into accounts gaps between subscription.
For a customer having been subscribed from 2023-01-01 to 2023-04-01 and then from 2023-05-01 to 2023-08-01, it seems to be counting days between 2023-01-01 and 2023-08-01.

Comment: overlaps need to be counted once?

Comment: @SalmanA Exactly. Days in the overlap should not be counted twice.

Comment: Please update your question with the SQL that you've managed to write so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is kind of a merge overlapping intervals problem:

- Find all rows that intersect the given range e.g. 2023-01-01 to 2023-12-31
- Process rows ordered by start date and assign group numbers as follows:
  If there is a gap between previous group and current row then start a new group
- Group the result by keys and group number, clamp the dates that are outside the range and calculate the difference between min and max date of each group

```sql
set @date1 = '2023-01-01';
set @date2 = '2023-12-31';

with cte1 as (
    select customer_id, start_at, end_at
    from t
    where start_at <= @date2 and end_at >= @date1
), cte2 as (
    select *, case when start_at <= max(end_at) over (partition by customer_id order by start_at rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) then 0 else 1 end as newgrp
    from cte1
), cte3 as (
    select *, sum(newgrp) over (partition by customer_id order by start_at) as grpnum
    from cte2
)
select
    customer_id,
    greatest(min(start_at), @date1) as date1,
    least(max(end_at), @date2) as date2,
    datediff(
        least(max(end_at), @date2),
        greatest(min(start_at), @date1)
    ) + 1 as diff
from cte3
group by customer_id, grpnum
```

[DB<>Fiddle - returns total for each island](https://dbfiddle.uk/v1v2bQro)
[DB<>Fiddle - returns total for all islands](https://dbfiddle.uk/xXGWmK60)

Comment: It is great and seems to work perfectly on a small amount of data, but when running it on all of my subscriptions (17777 records) it throws a 504 error. I will try running it on smaller batches of customers, with where clause.

Comment: 17777 is not much. (Covering) indexes might help though.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken, there are 116578 records.
@SalmanA what do you mean by "(Covering) indexes"?

Comment: Covering index is an index that contains more than one column and the first (few) satisfy the where clause and remaining ones used in select so MySQL doesn't have to touch the actual table.

Comment: Covering indexes have to be already implemented in the db, right? I can't add them when querying the data?

Comment: Be advised, the earlier query had a bug, which I have now fixed. Regarding covering indexes... yes they are part of database design, not select query.

Comment: Indeed, I realized it wasn't summing completely by customer_id. Thank you for the fix!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256889/discussion-between-loic-chabut-and-salman-a).

Answer (score 0):

One option is identifying overlapping date ranges with the arithmetic condition *t2.start_at > t1.start_at and t2.start_at < t1.end_at*. then, calculate the full extent of these overlaps using `LEAST` and `GREATEST` functions, and then exclude any ranges within these overlaps that have already been calculated :

```
with cte as (
  select t1.id, 
       t1.customer_id, 
       coalesce(least(t1.start_at, t2.start_at), t1.start_at) as start_at,
       coalesce(greatest(t1.end_at, t2.end_at), t1.end_at) as end_at,
       t2.id as to_del
  from mytable t1
  left join mytable t2 on t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
                        and t2.start_at > t1.start_at
                        and t2.start_at < t1.end_at
)
select customer_id, sum(DATEDIFF(end_at, start_at)) as total_subscription_days
from cte
where id not in (select to_del from cte where to_del is not null)
group by customer_id;
```

Results :

```
customer_id total_subscription_days
37          1463
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bx0kEYNF)

Comment: I get a 504 error, even when restricting the number of records queried.

Comment: restricting the number of records should be applied within the CTE. How have you attempted to execute this query? For optimal performance, an index is likely required. Please consider implementing this INDEX : `CREATE INDEX start_end_idx ON mytable (start_at, end_at)`

Comment: thank you for the explanation on INDEXES.
As for the restriction, I added ```and t1.customer_id < 100``` after your and t2.start_at < t1.end_at
@SalmanA's solution worked great.